# Slideshow not anchored correctly

Tags: html, css

I have inserted a slideshow into my webpage using a script I found online. However any text I add after shows up behind the image on the first line of the column. I want my buttons to be directly underneath, as if the image was its own line.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="ppt">
<li><img src="banner2.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="2"></img></li>
<li><img src="banner3.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="3"></img></li>
<li><img src="banner4.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="4"></img></li>
</ul>


<div align="center">
<button type="button" style="width:200; height:20; font-size: 8px; font:bold; color:#FFF; background-color:#666"  id="back"> << </button>
<button type="button" style="width:100; height:20; font-size: 8px; font:bold; color:#FFF; background-color:#666" id="stop">| |</button>
<button type="button" style="width:100; height:20; font-size: 8px; font:bold; color:#FFF; background-color:#666" id="play"> > </button>
<button type="button" style="width:200; height:20; font-size: 8px; font:bold; color:#FFF; background-color:#666"  id="fwd"> >> </button>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the images:

```
ul.ppt {
position: relative;
}

.ppt li {
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100;
}

.ppt img {

border: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ececec;
}
```

Here is the webpage:

www.cooswatershed.org/newhome2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `position: absolute;`, the slideshow is out of the 'page flow'. An easy way to make up for this is something like this:

```
ul.ppt {
height: 300px;
}
```